# alinear texto de tablas en bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, wordpress

estoy armando en bootstrap una pagina de contacto donde tengo un formulario y un mapa de google... la cosa es que lo arme con row, pero cuando lo veo en dispositivos moviles, queda muy feo, al verlo en PC todo bien, el tema es en responsive... miren el codigo...

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="col-4">
&nbsp;<h1 style="text-align: justify;"><a><img class="size-full wp-image-139 alignleft" src="http://cerouno24.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/flechita31.png" alt="" width="39" height="53" /></a>Contacto</h1>

    &nbsp;

<div class="card-body">
<p class="card-text">Usted puede continuar descubriendo nuestros productos simplemente poniéndose en contacto con nosotros, a la brevedad uno de nuestros asesores se comunicara.</p>
[contact-form-7 id="291" title="Formulario de contacto 1"]
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-1"></div>
<div class="col-7">
&nbsp;<h1><a href="http://cerouno24.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/flechita31.png"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-139" src="http://cerouno24.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/flechita31.png" alt="" width="39" height="53" /></a>¿Donde estamos?</h1>
&nbsp;
<iframe style="border: 0;" tabindex="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3405.46620791822!2d-64.16830578530687!3d-31.401278902662483!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9432980c25a03c29%3A0x13c0caa8baa234be!2sCochabamba%201676%2C%20C%C3%B3rdoba!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sar!4v1600783244071!5m2!1ses-419!2sar" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" aria-hidden="false"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estás usando columnas absolutas, debes hacer uso de las clases de columna responsivas de acuerdo al tamaño del dispositivo donde ejecutes la página. Revisa: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#grid-options